# generalized aggregate in vhdl

Tags: arrays, vhdl, fpga

I have an array / vector and I want to generate a new array by processing the first. A simple example of what I need is that every i-th element from the new array is the sum of the i-1, i, and i+1 elements from the first one.
I know this can be done very easily in a sequential manner by iterating through the array. I was wandering if there any kind of assigning expression that would generalize this and make this a parallel operation.(like in math: new[i] := old[i - 1] + old[i] + old[i + 1], where i ∈ (1, n) ).

Comment: Write a function that returns the initialised array.

Comment: In a comment you expressed intent to deal with 1000 or more elements, that number and element size colors implementation in a finite resource FPGA and may not fit. You hadn't indicated how many elements nor their size and that tells us your question is unclear. Theoretical questions without complete parameters likely can't get useful answers. There can be a time/complexity trade off where you can use fewer resources across some number of clocks to complete the function.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is about parallelism, I assume that you are interested in the hardware that will be synthesized from your VHDL description, not by the simulation.

Parallelism is a matter of *when all these additions take place*? If your design is synchronous - let's say of the rising edge of a clock named `clk` - then:

```
subtype word: unsigned(7 downto 0);
type word_array is array(natural range <>) of word;
signal a: word_array(0 to 15);
signal b: word_array(1 to 14);
...
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    for i in 1 to 14 loop
      b(i) <= a(i - 1) + a(i) + a(i + 1);
    end loop;
  end if;
end process;
```

will compute in parallel the 14 values in array `b` at each rising edge of the clock. And it will instantiate as many 8-bits adders as needed to do this. The question is not whether you are using a `for` loop or something else, it is really *when do these operations take place*? The answer is in the description: *during the very same clock period*.

You could overload the `"+"` operator to work on vectors:

```
function "+"(a, b: word_array) return word_array is
  constant n: positive := a'length;
  variable va: word_array(0 to n - 1) := a;
  variable vb: word_array(0 to n - 1) := b;
  variable sum: word_array(0 to n - 1);
begin
  if n = 1 then
    sum(0) := va(0) + vb(0);
  else
    sum := (va(0 to n / 2 - 1) + vb(0 to n / 2 - 1)) &
           (va(n / 2 to n - 1) + vb(n / 2 to n - 1));
  end if;
  return sum;
end function "+";
```

and use it to *apparently* write a more parallel description:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    b <= a(0 to 13) + a(1 to 14) + a(2 to 15);
  end if;
end process;
```

but it would make no difference and the resulting hardware would be the same.

You could also use a generate statement to do the same:

```
g: for i in 1 to 14 generate
  process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      b(i) <= a(i - 1) + a(i) + a(i + 1);
    end if;
  end process;
end generate g;
```

but, again, it would make no difference for the synthesizer.